# CSS add a image vertical center with text in a div

Tags: css

I tried to v-align a image with a text in my link.
Until now I have used a background image to perfectly v-center the image of my text

CSS

```
.label  { 
margin: 0 0 0 15px;
padding: 0;
color: #fff;
}

a.moreinfo {
background: url(../images/gallery/add.png) no-repeat left center;
cursor: pointer; 
}
```

HTML

```
<a class='moreinfo'><span class='label'>MORE INFO</span></a>
```

Now I want to try not to use background images, but insert an image in the html code (img src). I tried using vertical-align: middle, but the image is not aligned precisely like the one in the background. How could I do to get the same thing with an image included in the html code? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can center an element in another:

```
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

You can find more in this link: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/ .

Answer (score 0):

I've found something like this to work very well for me:

```
a.moreinfo {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

a.moreinfo span, a.moreinfo img {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50%;
  float: none;
}
```

When you vertically align while setting display to table, floated elements won't work as expected. The parent should have a set width or the default width will set to auto and, again, not work as expected.

Comment: It's a good solution, but if the image is smaller (height) than the text is a big problem.